# Infer presence of value from method call in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsc, typechecking

I have a specific pattern to check whether a value is present or not after a user submission.

Since I don't want to repeat this logic multiple times, I extracted it into a `valIsBlank` method so the logic is centralized. The problem is that the TypeScript compiler does not infer the presence (or not) of the field correctly anymore.

Here is some sample code to illustrate the issue :

```
type Value<T> = T | null | undefined;

function getOr<T>(value: Value<T>, fallback: T): T {
    // With this : the code works as expected with no tsc errors ✅
    // const isBlank = value === undefined || value === null || (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);

    // With this : the line 'return value;' triggers an error ❌
    const isBlank = valIsBlank(value);

    // With this : the line 'return value;' triggers an error ❌
    // const isBlank = ((value: Value<T>) => value === undefined || value === null || (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0))(value);

    if (isBlank) {
        return fallback;
    }

    return value;
}

function valIsBlank<T>(value: Value<T>): boolean {
    return value === undefined || value === null || (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);
}
```

Is there a way for the compiler to understand what's happening in `isBlank` and infer that if it returns `false`, then the type of `value` becomes simply `T` ? Like it does when the check is inlined directly in the function.

Naturally, I'd like to avoid casting the value with `as T` or `!`.

Comment: The blank string part is a bit weird, but generally speaking you want `isBlank`'s return type to be a *type predicate* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOxqMN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks. I forgot about type predicate. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: Oh and regarding the string part, I wanted to mimic the behavior of Rails' `blank?` method : https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F but I agree it's not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the compiler to understand that the output of a `boolean`-returning function like `valIsBlank()` acts as a type guard on its input, you need to annotate the return type with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

If `valIsBlank(value)` returns `true` then you know that `value` is `undefined` or `null` or a "blank string" (which seems to be a string consisting only of spaces).  So you could write it this way:

```
declare function valIsBlank<T>(value: Value<T>):
    value is null | undefined | (T & BlankString);
```

There isn't actually a specific type in TypeScript corresponding to a blank string; for that you'd need something like *regular expression validated string types* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160), which aren't part of the language.  I'm not going to worry much about it because it seems to be beside the point of the question.  For now I'll just define it as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of a few likely string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and move on:

```
type BlankString = "" | " " | "  " | "   " // ‍♂️ who knows
```

Let's test it:

```
function getOr<T>(value: Value<T>, fallback: T): T {
    const isBlank = valIsBlank(value);
    if (isBlank) { return fallback; }
    return value; // okay
}
```

Looks good. The call to `valIsBlank(value)` acts as a type guard on `value`.  TypeScript supports [saving type guard results in `const` variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants), so the `isBlank` variable acts as an aliased condition, which can then be used to narrow `value` when checked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QDwBUB8UC8V1QA+UAdkggkVEiQCYQBmAliRLQNwCwAUDwzQGNgTAPYkoAcwjAA8gCcMmABQA3RCgBcsdWiwAaKA0QIARnAEBrLegCU1qAG8eASAFiAzsChN3AIQRwJBa4UGoIAJJ+AUGqOjZc3M5MDFBKPv6BFjaOUHLSSHLiRhRmluxQAL4uecAF4mEo5QD0TVAiFnAgPFW83KCQUBlBAMrAciwSIQBEU1Szs8SzUAvLUGuzLVCAfBuA7LuAsASAQmSA8H9QAO4AFiJQFiQip+48fILCYqGIkUMWirHIEFrwv0UdhcDWgPlI5EoxBo9GYrFoVCUBAAZINohZRuMSBJsk5EjU6m9frgcHgYYwWGwiMRQSS8GQKNSXM4lP0ICIUrTSXgAOSeLESHlQZGo0EAOjGTAAtkobGKEBBscBznSoAAGeLdIA)